# Pandas Dataframes sum value counts of different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, series

I just started to analyze a little csv file and I created a Dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

The Dataframe contains columns from diag1 to diag12, each column contains a string or a NaN value. My objective is to create a chart and show the number of apparitions of each code.

[image]

How I should sum the value_counts result for example in this case for the diag1 and diag2 columns, I should have a DataFrame or a series with the sum of both series. For example, the code **J20.9** should appear with a value of **194**, **88** from the **diag1** series and **106** from the **diag2**.

How I should do this sum for the value counts of the columns from **diag1** to **diag12** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

final_count = Counter()
for col in df.columns:
    final_count = Counter(df[col]) + final_count

print(final_count)
```

The final_count will have counts for all the values. Use `pd.Series(final_count)` to convert it to series.